# I am an instrument if I am joined with a board, to which you could use me to play an abundance of chords

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I am an instrument if I am joined with a board,*
>
> *To which you could use me to play an abundance of chords.*
>
> *I am a foundation if I am joined with a stone,*
>
> *To which you and things associated could depend on me alone.*
>
> *I am a provider of access if I am joined with a card,*
>
> *To which I can open without disregard.*
>
> *I rhyme with a word similar to I and myself.*
>
> *I am often used in a space surrounded by bookshelves.*
>
> *What do I do for doors, I can do for ideas.*
>
> *Can you guess what I am, or is the answer unclear?*

---

I made up this riddle for fun. Hope you enjoy!

Hints for the answer are below.

---

**Hint:**

> *Not only do I open, but I first unlock;*
>  *Though if I am not in hand, you might knock knock knock.*

Comment: Apologies for all the crazy edits. I do not know how to format my posts off by heart, so I copy my previous posts and then change up the lines for my new riddle. Unfortunately, I did not proof-read this riddle before posting it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are a

> **KEY**

I am an instrument if I am joined with a board,
To which you could use me to play an abundance of chords.

> A **KEYBOARD** is a musical instrument

I am a foundation if I am joined with a stone,
To which you things associated could depend on me alone.

> A **KEYSTONE** is the central stone/principle on which everything depends

I am a provider of access if I am joined with a card,
To which I can open without disregard.

> A **KEYCARD** can be used to open electronic locks

I rhyme with a word similar to I and myself.

> **KEY** rhymes with **ME**

I am often used in a space surrounded by bookshelves.

> Maybe keys on a computer in a library?
> Or perhaps a musical key, in a place with lots of music books?

What do I do for doors, I can do for ideas.

> A key can open/unlock a door, but not sure about a key opening/unlocking an idea.
> From @m1gp0z, it could relate to a "key concept"?

Hint

> Not only do I open, but I first unlock;
> Though if I am not in hand, you might knock knock knock.
>
> If you don't have your key, you'll have to knock on the door.

Comment: How did you come up with that so quickly? You are brilliant!

Comment: Man that was a mean snipe..

Comment: @user477343 It was the card one that made it click, combined with the rhyme.  Thanks for the puzzle!  I'm still working through the other lines due to the edits and work getting in the way.

Comment: "What I do for doors, I can do for ideas" makes me think of rot13(xrl pbaprcg) of a lesson

Comment: @RickvanOsta Sorry!  I didn't even see another answer...wasn't trying to be mean!

Comment: @m1gp0z Thanks!  I'm still not certain about the exact answer for that line, but I've included your thoughts in the post.

Comment: @user477343: Not trying to toot my own horn, but I got it from the title. It seemed like an obvious tip, but maybe that's because I'm not native English and I generally only use "board" in the "keyboard" sense (albeit the PC version).

Comment: @Flater Ditto! toot toot

Comment: At the risk of nitpicking, the kind of 'stone' the question asks about is not part of a foundation. It's part of an arch.

Comment: @DJClayworth Aye, the stone OP should mean is a [cornerstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornerstone), not a keystone.

Comment: @DJClayworth I agree that is the first definition of the word, but would argue that the second definition is "the central principle or part of a policy, system, etc., on which all else depends".  Keystone and foundation seem pretty widely accepted as synonymous.

Comment: @hagfy: My first thought was "corner", since in construction the "keystone" would be about as far away from the foundation as one can get (the keystone of an arch is in the top center).

Comment: @supercat Again, I agree...in construction, or using the first definition of the word, that is correct.  However, the word 'keystone' has multiple definitions.  OP doesn't say the answer for those lines has to be a stone, just 'KEY' plus the literal 'STONE'.  Nobody is complaining about the keyboard not being a literal 2x4 or "the panel of keys that operate a computer or typewriter", so I don't understand why keystone is such an issue.

Comment: @J... no I did mean keystone, but perhaps I should have used the word **basis** as opposed to **foundation**. I just used the former word because *instrument* and *foundation* have the same amount of syllables, so it sounded better.

Comment: @Flater I use board in the "wooden board" sense, hahah. But, I am glad you thought a bit differently, because it worked to your advantage! :)

Comment: @supercat yeah, but I sometimes use the word "keystone" to mean foundation, but I see what you mean (e.g. look at the title of [this article](https://gurushots.com/article/black-and-white-photography-guide)). I guess I should have used the word **basis**.